# How to detect the slug of the Category page i'm on? (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, slug

I keep finding tutorials on listing all the slugs on the internet but can't seem a function or line of code that can echo/return me the slug of the category i'm on so I can save it on a variable.

Does anyone know what it is?
I need to be able to use it in archive-product.php

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$slugs = array();
foreach( (get_the_category()) as $category ) { 
    array_push( $slugs, $category->slug );
} 
var_dump( $slugs );
```

(untested)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

**Edit:**

Tested and works correctly. Try adding to archive.php (temporarily) and make sure your url is something like: `mysite.com/category/uncategorized/` . I suspect you may not be calling the correct template file or perhaps not actually browsing any categories.

Comment: This don't work in my case. I get an empty array. Maybe this has changed in newer versions of woocommerce. Since this question has many visits, could you please update the answer or confirm if this still works? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

The category slug should be available in global variable `$wp_query`.

Try this in *yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php*:

```
global $wp_query;
$cat_slug = $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'];
echo $cat_slug;
```

The other method with `get_the_category()` may work for normal posts in *archive.php* but I had no success with it in *archive-product.php*.

Comment: If you want the product category ID (instead of the slug), see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/198425/11807

Comment: Good answer. In the last version of woocommerce is the only solution that I can confirm that still works. Thanks a lot!